# how i find out uset check and unchecked checkboxes?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots, qcheckbox

My program have a set of `checkbox`, When user check a `checkbox`, i should `call`  `slot1()` and user uncheck `checkbox`, i should `call` `slot2()`,But i can't understand when user checks and when unchecked.

**My questions** is, How can i find out user check and unchecked `checkbox`? It's very important that i differ between check and unckeck.

**Notes:** i didn't find any signal related to uncked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are signals `clicked(bool)` and `toggled(bool)`:

> If the button is checkable, checked is true if the button is checked,
>   or false if the button is unchecked.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html#clicked
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html#toggled